# User editing the original question to make it a new question

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits

The frequency of the following to happen, is quite high.

User asks a question. Somebody answers it correctly which solves the problem/issue. Instead of upvote or accept, the user edits the question and puts forth a new scenario/question that arose....after applying the answer, which is completely different from the original one.(And is not caused due to the answer)

Is there any other mechanism which can advise the user against such behaviour?

Is there any way to not let the user edit the question after getting the answer for the original question? Or should this be of no concern?

(or should i ask this question somewhere else, in some other way)

Comment: Rollback the edit, comment suggesting new questions should be asked as new questions and if its repeated flag requesting a lock

Comment: Voting this question up because it's well written and has a good chance of hitting the search due to the keywords used in the title. The "Chameleon" question, while canonical, is poorly worded for new users to know what it means.